# Subsection numbering should be arabic (1.1, 1.2 etc) not A B C

Tags: sectioning, numbering

My sections are numbered arabic. I want to get subsection numbering also arabic as 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 etc. I have searched many forums and got these codes but it does not work for me. People say it works for us. I am using this code.

```
\def\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\def\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\def\thesubsubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}
```

Only the first instruction works. I also used `\renewcommand` instead of `\def`.

Comment: This *should* work. Use a recursive definition `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}} \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}} \renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}` instead. Why doesn't it work for you? What are you doing differently? Perhaps include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that highlights your problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But it does not work.

Comment: You did see that I asked you a bunch of other questions as well, right? I'll reiterate: "Why does it not work when it works on 'many forums' for other people? What are you doing differently? Include a  [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that highlights your problem."

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

There are classes that use `\Alph` for subsections. Example `revtex4-1`:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

> [image: revtex4-1, default]

However, redefining the counter macro `\the<counter>` usually works as expected:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand*{\p@subsection}{}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}
\renewcommand*{\p@subsubsection}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section}
\label{sec}
\subsection{Subsection}
\label{subsec}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\label{subsubsec}
References: \ref{sec}, \ref{subsec}, and \ref{subsubsec}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: If you say `\label{x}` after the `\subsubsection` and then `\ref{x}`, you get `1 1.1 1.1.1` because `revtex4-1` redefines `\p@subsubsection` to `\thesection\,\thesubsection\,` (and also `\p@subsection`, of course).

Comment: @egreg: Thanks. I have updated the question.

Comment: I was bitten by this problem, this is why I remember it. ;-)