# How to change subsection numbering in the main body of text?

Tags: numbering

I want to change the numbering of my subsections from A, B, C etc, to 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 etc.

I use `\def\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{section}}` however it only changed the numbering in the table of contents, leaving the alpha in the main body of text.

Why isnt it changing in the main body of text?

```
\def\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{section}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Please post a small, yet complete, code reproducing the problem.

Comment: A, B, C isn't the default, so how are you obtaining this output?

Answer (score 1):

Will this meet the requirement?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand*{\p@subsection}{}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}
\renewcommand*{\p@subsubsection}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section}
\label{sec}
\subsection{Subsection}
\label{subsec}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\label{subsubsec}
References: \ref{sec}, \ref{subsec}, and \ref{subsubsec}.
\end{document}
```

from--[Subsection numbering should be arabic (1.1, 1.2 etc) not A B C](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124043/subsection-numbering-should-be-arabic-1-1-1-2-etc-not-a-b-c?rq=1)

Comment: In the standard classes (e.g., `article` etc) the default divisional numbering is Arabic. Therefore your code is superfluous.