# Same numbering of subsection and section in main body and table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, numbering, ieeetran, subsection

Basically the same issue as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520129/how-to-change-subsection-numbering-in-the-main-body-of-text).
I was able to change the numbering of my subsections in table of contents but the change was not reflected in the main body.

I am basically using IEEE conference template. Everything is the same formatting wise with the only change being me changing the numbering in table of contents from A, B, C to .1, .2, .3 etc.

The fix in the post above did not work for me. Any other help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and show your try as [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Usually, these are in sync, so we need an example if your code is treating them differently. But if this is a conference template, you *shouldn't* change this kind of thing because it is configured to ensure a standard style.